# Changing the time it takes for the hover tooltip to show up in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How can I change the time it takes for the hover tooltip  to show up when I hover on a function in Eclipse PyDev?

I couldn't find a parameter in the preferences window:

[image]

Example of hover tooltip:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special configuration to change the time to show the hover. The current time is the same time which the system takes to send the hover event to Eclipse/PyDev (so, if you want to change that time, you have to change it in the target OS).

As a note, your screenshot of the preferences page seems to be from a pretty old PyDev version, so, I'd recommend updating it -- it has already improved greatly from that version ;)